# How many Star Trek species possess 'mega-strength'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

When Commander Riker requests that Data bend a 2.5" diameter bar of “parsteel” during a hearing to determine if Data was the property of Starfleet, Data easily bends the bar in half and places in on the table. Captain Picard objects to the demonstration, stating that there are many lifeforms that possess “mega-strength” so the demonstration is irrelevant. ([TNG: 2x09 "The Measure Of A Man"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_%28episode%29))

Many races seem to be physically stronger than Human; Vulcan, Klingon and Romulan immediately come to mind, but they would obviously not qualify as possessing “mega-strength”. Has there been any depiction or mention of any particular race or individual demonstrating strength on par with or superior to Data's?

Comment: I think the quote is [“meta-human strength”](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/135.txt), not “mega-strength”. [“Meta”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta#Adjective), in this context, means “higher than”, i.e. greater strength than humans.

Comment: And it’s “plasteel”. *\*Pedant-gasm\**

Comment: On par or superior to Data? Even Borg don't possess Data's strength. Probably Q would fit in, although they've never displayed such strength while in human form.

Comment: @pauldwaite - the script was "meta-human strength", the line in the show was "mega strength.".

Comment: @Richard: oh, fair play. I stand by “plasteel” though.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite -I'm pretty much a stud but couldn't bend that thickness of tightly wrapped copy paper.

Comment: [Damnit.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we-H0ZQZJkI&t=4m00s)

Comment: the answer is, of course, "any species that has ever fought Worf."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### In the Star Trek Universe advanced technology equalizes/negates physical advantages such as strength, so there is very little reason for Star Trek to go into keeping a running tab of races with meta-human strength.

If I were to look at the TOS, alone we have a few aliens to choose from:

- The Salt Monster, (Nancy Carter), able to overpower humans with almost no resistance what so ever. She was the last of her kind and we never see her at peak performance but her strength was not in question.
- Khan, the augments from Old Earth, whose superhuman strength was on par with Vulcans.
- The Gorn, far greater than human strength. Human hand-to-hand contests were completely useless. Kirk was forced to improvise and create a primitive cannon to bring down his opponent.
- The Kelvans, though we don't see them use their strength, they were reputed to be larger and stronger than humans, just wearing human-like bodies for disguises.
- The androids found by Harcort Fenton Mudd, each physically superior to humans, perhaps even as strong, physically as Data.
- Apollo (and likely his other gods) through the use of his technology and drawing worship from humans, he increased his strength ten fold.
- Q: There is no reason that Q and his ilk couldn't be as strong as they wanted to be, just by willing it. Seeing how no rational being would attempt to physically attack one is the only reason we don't see one using such strength.
- Trelane: See notes about Q.
- The Horta: Able to tunnel through rock by augmenting its heat profile. It must have a degree of superhuman strength and durability to use its physical abilities in this fashion.

#### From Next Generation:

- The Borg: Due to their nanoprobe and cybernetic physical enhancements, an ordinary Borg drone was far stronger than the average human, even if they were human originally.

#### From Deep Space Nine:

As noted by Morgan:

- The Founders/Changelings - despite their ability to take on humanoid shapes, they were capable of incredible feats of strength due to their malleable physical structure and ability to mimic the appearance of anything.

#### From the Voyager Series:

As noted by Morgan:

- Species 8472 from Fluidic Space possessed vast physical strength.
- The Voth: Descended from Earth in the time of the dinosaurs, it is likely the Voth with their reptilian DNA would possess physical strength far greater than the Human norm, though no comparison of such strength was displayed.

Comment: That's a good breakdown. I would probably add species 8472 from 'Voyager' and the Founders/Changelings from 'DS9'. Q and Trelane provides a bit of a problem though due to their seemingly unlimited inherent powers. Among them though, probably only Apollo and species 8472 and maybe one other could actually challenge Data for pure physical strength.

Comment: Yes, Morgan, your additions make sense. I only wrote this list from memory because I was still at work. I will update it a bit when time permits. Thanks you for your thoughtful reply.

Comment: I look forward to your refined answer. Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: Your last point confuses me. The Voth were humanoid in size and shape and Chakotay spent much of the episode in their close company. Their ships were enormous because they were technologically advanced, not because they were physically huge.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, the [Brikar](http://stexpanded.wikia.com/wiki/Brikar) would be one example. Zak Kebron is the most well-known one.